# Using whitespace in JLabel vs. ipadx/ipady in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, gridbaglayout

In my project I am layering `JPanels` on top of eachother which are, for the most part, copies of eachother. I do this in such a way that allows the components position to be exactly the same as the related ones above and below. In some places I need the text of a `JLabel` from underneath to be shown, in which case, the `JLabel` on top would be empty. However, an empty or null JLabel will distort the positioning.

So far I have found 2 solutions. One is to use an *x* amount of whitespaces in the *upper layer* which will give the `JLabel` an equal amount of *weight* as the corresponding label below it.

The other solution is to give `ipadx` and `ipady` values in the *top layer* empty `JLabel` in a way that equals the area of the corresponding label below it.

These solutions seem very "hackish" to me but it's all that I could come up with. I'm worried that this will not be reliable. Are either of these solutions acceptable? If so, which way is more reliable?

EDIT: adding visuals
This is what you see when the panels are correctly lined up.
[image]

This is what you see when a JLabel is null and the panels are not correctly lined up. Red represents top layer panel
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you experimented with the GridBagLayout's **anchor** value?

From Oracle documentation:

"Used when the component is smaller than its display area to determine where (within the area) to place the component. Valid values (defined as GridBagConstraints constants) are CENTER (the default), PAGE_START, PAGE_END, LINE_START, LINE_END, FIRST_LINE_START, FIRST_LINE_END, LAST_LINE_END, and LAST_LINE_START"

Comment: I have played around with the anchor values, but I couldn't get what I needed. Although, I gotta admit I'm not 100% clear in my understanding of anchor despite what I've read up on it. GridBagLayout is a big monster to tame.